# Symbol collision when building Windows 64bit DLL

Tags: c, windows, dll, compilation, symbols

I added function `ShowWindow()` to [my library](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib) and it fails on DLL generation only on Windows 64 bit due to a collision with `user32.dll` same name symbol.

I'm aware that calling conventions `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` are ignored in 64 bit and that could be a reason for the collision but... why it does not complaint about my other function `ShowCursor()`? Same symbol it's also inside `user32.dll`! I don't understand it...

Also wondering if there is any solution to keep my `ShowWindow()` on all platforms.

Comment: To use standard library names for your symbols is not a good idea, the risk for collision is a problem that should not be ignored. Said this, the reason could be that in win32 the function names are decorated postfixing them with an `@` followed by a number expressing the sum of the sizes of all parameters, while under 64bits the name is as is. If your function has a different parameters size the names are different in Win32. In your sample do you use both functions? Maybe don't happen for `ShowCursor` because it isn't used? (I can't study all your code just for this...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I'm aware about the calling convention symbols naming, also checked `user32.dll` `ShowWindow()` and `ShowCursor()` parameters to see if it could be related to the fact that one is working but not the other... It fails on my library DLL generation, not in a sample.

Comment: I would make some check, but your code is too big. Could craft a small piece of code that reproduces the problem. Are you sure that there is no catch-22 calling those functions from inside your dll?

Comment: Hi @Frankie_C, thank you very much, don't worry, you give me a tip with your comment and I think I found the reason. `ShowWindow()` is called internally by window inititalization function (through GLFW library) while `ShowCursor()` is never called because it is indirectly set using `window->cursorMode`. Thanks again for your answers and your time! :)

Comment: Happy to have been of any help...